# date trunc 6 months

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to show 6 months worth of data.  For example from the 1st of September to 1st March inclusive.

The code below starts from the 1st of September but finishes on today

```
 date >= date_trunc('month' , now() - ('6 months' :: interval))
```

I am working on Postgres.

Comment: E.g. `date BETWEEN date_trunc('month' , now() - interval '6 months') AND date_trunc('month' , now())`?

Comment: spot on! thanks so much

Comment: How to use it for grouping date records in 6 months of interval using group by?